# Switching ROS local planner in pre-existing project

Tags: ros, path-finding

Currently, I am working on a autonomous robot, which has a non-standard method of steering. Rather than using tank steering, it instead has two pivot wheels in the rear and two front-powered wheels.
Because the base_local_planner that is currently being used does not have any support for this setup, the planning is basically useless.

The core question is:
Is it possible to change the local planner used from base_local_planner to something like the teb_local_planner, which at least has support for the shape of the robot, and how would something like this be achieved?

Additional information:

- RVIZ is used for the cost-maps.
- Linux distro is Kinetic
- Current planner is base_local_planner
- global planner used is global_planner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that the local planners you are talking about only support differential steering or skid steering.  Sounds like your robot is more similar to Ackermann steering.  I am not aware of any out of the box options for Ackermann in ROS, but I do know it has been done with [hamster](http://wiki.ros.org/Robots/Hamster), if you can find how they did it, it might solve your issue.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! We've managed to find out how, still not sure if this is "correct" though.
We edited a config file where it was set to use base_local_planner, but instead we changed that to teb_local_planner, which solved a lot of our problems because it allows for the configuration of a minimum turning circle.